# Run Macro from LibreOffice extension JAVA

Tags: java, macros, libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

I am trying to run a Macro (the macro is in Writer Standard.Voto.Main) from a java button in a extension.

This is the button:

```
<dlg:button dlg:id="Bt_voto" dlg:tab-index="2" dlg:left="78" dlg:top="15" dlg:width="52" dlg:height="12" dlg:tag="B" dlg:value="Voto"><script:eventscript:event-name="on-performaction" script:macro-name="vnd.sun.star.UNO:ConfigChange" script:language="UNO"/>
```

I call the method from this class:

```
public boolean callHandlerMethod(XDialog dialog, Object eventObject, String methodName)
        throws WrappedTargetException {
    if (methodName.equals(ConfigChange)) {

        try {
            String param = "";
            // String cmd =
            // "Standard.Conversion.ConvertHTMLToWord?langauge=Basic&location=application";
            String cmd = "Standard.Voto.Main?langauge=Basic&location=Document";
            System.out.println("Running macro on " + param);
            Macro macObj = new Macro();
            macObj.executeMacro(cmd, new Object[] { param });
            System.out.println("Completed?");
            onOkButtonPressed();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
            // e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

and the Macro.class is:

```
class Macro {

    public Object executeMacro(String strMacroName, Object[] aParams) throws BootstrapException
    {

        String oooExecFolder = "C:/Program Files (x86)/LibreOffice 5/program";


        try {
            System.out.println("Completed1");
            XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExecFolder);
            XMultiComponentFactory xMultiComponentFactory = xContext.getServiceManager();
            XComponentLoader xcomponentloader = (XComponentLoader) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XComponentLoader.class,xMultiComponentFactory.createInstanceWithContext("com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext));
            System.out.println("Completed2");


            com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument mxDoc = openWriter(xContext);

            XScriptProviderSupplier xScriptPS = (XScriptProviderSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(XScriptProviderSupplier.class, xcomponentloader);
            XScriptProvider xScriptProvider = xScriptPS.getScriptProvider(); 
            XScript xScript = xScriptProvider.getScript("vnd.sun.star.script:"+strMacroName); 

            short[][] aOutParamIndex = new short[1][1];
            Object[][] aOutParam = new Object[1][1];

            aParams = new String[2];

            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            Object result = xScript.invoke(aParams, aOutParamIndex, aOutParam);
            System.out.println("xScript invoke macro " + strMacroName);

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            throw new RuntimeException(e);

        }
        return oooExecFolder; 
    }

    public static com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument openWriter(com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xContext)
    {

        com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader xCLoader; 
        com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument xDoc = null; 
        com.sun.star.lang.XComponent xComp = null; 

        try { 
            // get the remote office service manager 
            com.sun.star.lang.XMultiComponentFactory xMCF = 
                xContext.getServiceManager(); 

            Object oDesktop = xMCF.createInstanceWithContext( 
                                        "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", xContext); 

            xCLoader = (com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader) 
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, 
                                          oDesktop); 
            com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue [] szEmptyArgs = 
                new com.sun.star.beans.PropertyValue [0];
           /*
            ArrayList<PropertyValue> props = new ArrayList<PropertyValue>();
            PropertyValue p = new PropertyValue();
            p.Name = "Hidden";
            p.Value = new Boolean(true);
            props.add(p);

            PropertyValue[] properties = new PropertyValue[props.size()];
            props.toArray(properties);
            String strDoc = "private:factory/swriter";
            xComp = xCLoader.loadComponentFromURL(strDoc, "_blank", 0, properties);            
            */
            String strDoc = "private:factory/swriter"; 
            xComp = xCLoader.loadComponentFromURL(strDoc, "_blank", 0, szEmptyArgs); 
            xDoc = (com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument) 
                UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument.class, 
                                          xComp); 

        } catch(Exception e){  
            System.err.println(" Exception " + e); 
            e.printStackTrace(System.err); 
        }        
        return xDoc; 
    }
}
```

If I run this class the bootstrap works, but it's terminated at this line:

```
XComponentContext xContext = BootstrapSocketConnector.bootstrap(oooExecFolder);
```

without error. Can you help me?

Answer (score 0):

It is much easier to call the Basic macro directly from the dialog.  This works even if the rest of the extension uses Java.  Be sure to use the correct [Script URI](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/Scripting/Scripting_Framework_URI_Specification).

```
<dlg:button dlg:id="Bt_voto" dlg:tab-index="3" dlg:left="173" dlg:top="88" dlg:width="51" dlg:height="13" dlg:value="Voto">
  <script:event script:event-name="on-performaction" script:macro-name="vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Voto.Main?language=Basic&amp;location=application" script:language="Script"/>
</dlg:button>
```

However if you do need to go through Java for some other reason, then keep reading.  It looks like you tried to combine code from two different projects:

- https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension
- https://github.com/kinow/bootstrapconnector

The problem is that some commands should only be done once, and each project does them, resulting in duplication.  Don't bootstrap a second time.  Instead, store the context somewhere so it can be passed to the Macro class when needed.

Below are the relevant parts of the code that worked for me.  For testing, I added a main method to StarterProjectImpl.java.  This made it possible to see the error messages.

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    com.sun.star.uno.XComponentContext xContext = null;
    try {
        xContext = com.sun.star.comp.helper.Bootstrap.bootstrap();
        ActionOneDialog actionOneDialog = new ActionOneDialog(xContext);
        actionOneDialog.show();
    } catch (Exception exc) {
        exc.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ActionOneDialog(XComponentContext xContext) {
    m_xContext = xContext;
    this.dialog = DialogHelper.createDialog("ActionOneDialog.xdl", xContext, this);
}

public boolean callHandlerMethod(XDialog dialog, Object eventObject, String methodName) throws WrappedTargetException {
    if (methodName.equals(ConfigChange)) {
        try {
            String cmd = "Standard.Voto.Main?language=Basic&location=application";
            Macro macObj = new Macro(m_xContext);
        }
    }

public Object executeMacro(String strMacroName, Object[] aParams)
{
    String oooExecFolder = "C:/Program Files (x86)/LibreOffice 5/program";
    try {
        XMultiComponentFactory xMultiComponentFactory = m_xContext.getServiceManager();
        Object oDesktop = xMultiComponentFactory.createInstanceWithContext( 
                        "com.sun.star.frame.Desktop", m_xContext); 
        XComponentLoader xcomponentloader = (com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader) 
            UnoRuntime.queryInterface(com.sun.star.frame.XComponentLoader.class, 
                                  oDesktop); 
        com.sun.star.text.XTextDocument mxDoc = openWriter(m_xContext);

        XScriptProviderSupplier xScriptPS = (XScriptProviderSupplier) UnoRuntime.queryInterface(
                XScriptProviderSupplier.class, mxDoc);
        XScriptProvider xScriptProvider = xScriptPS.getScriptProvider(); 
        XScript xScript = xScriptProvider.getScript("vnd.sun.star.script:"+strMacroName); 
    } catch (Exception e) { 
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**:

Here are step by step instructions.  In LibreOffice, go to `Tools -> Macros -> Organize Macros -> LibreOffice Basic`.  Under `My Macros & Dialogs -> Standard -> Voto`, paste this code:

```vb
Sub Main
    MsgBox("Hello, Voto!")
End Sub
```

Next follow the [Get Started instructions](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension).
Expand `dialog -> ActionOneDialog.xdl` and go to the `Source` tab.  Paste the following code after `</dlg:button>`.

```
<dlg:button dlg:id="Bt_voto" dlg:tab-index="4" dlg:left="100" dlg:top="88" dlg:width="51" dlg:height="13" dlg:value="Voto">
  <script:event script:event-name="on-performaction" script:macro-name="vnd.sun.star.script:Standard.Voto.Main?language=Basic&amp;location=application" script:language="Script"/>
</dlg:button>
```

Now run it to add the extension.  Finally in LibreOffice, go to `Starter Project -> Action One` and click `Voto`.  The result should be this:

[image: result]

**EDIT 2**:

From my experience, it is not possible to insert a field from within a dialog event handler.  Instead, wait until after the dialog has finished executing and then insert the field.

For this project, it should work to modify `show()` in ActionOneDialog.java.  After the command `dialog.execute()`, write Java code to insert the field using the dispatcher.

Comment: thanks for your quick response, another question, if i call the macro from the button the method configchange become unless or no? this code that you write go in startprojectimpl? thank for your patience

Comment: If the button calls Basic directly, then there is no need for the Macro class.  If the button calls Basic through Java, then these methods are in the same location as they are in your code, except for the main routine which I placed in [StarterProjectImpl.java](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension/blob/master/source/org/libreoffice/example/comp/StarterProjectImpl.java).  The constructor goes in [ActionOneDialog.java](https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension/tree/master/source/org/libreoffice/example/dialog).

Comment: i restart the project whit the default starterproject. https://pastebin.com/tnbYXA99 this is my StarterProjectImpl.java if i run the class, i dont have error and LibreOffice start, i create manually a new document and the botton work's good (also the macro work). but if a start the extension the botton doesn't work. Can you help me to implement this class? thank you very much

Comment: Could you post the entire project on a site like dropbox to download?

Comment: I'm restarted, it's this project: https://github.com/smehrbrodt/libreoffice-starter-extension and i add only the bootstrap in the ActionOneDialog.java class. i try a lot of thing but the macro start only if i use the main and start the class.

Comment: and a simple dialog whit 3 button: strandard.voto.main - standard.classe.main-standard.student.main in the script uri

Comment: Edited answer to give step-by-step instructions.

Comment: i understand because the "hello word!" work, but my macro dosn't. this is my macro : https://pastebin.com/RZWeyK1V . it was registred, i insert a placeholder called voto <Voto>

Comment: It will not work that way.  See edit 2 in my answer.